# How do I import FASTA files into Haploview?

Tags: bioinformatics, population-genetics, software

I'm trying to produce a haplotype network and so have decided to use the software haploview. However I'm having some problems importing my sequences into the software.

I Have my sequences in a FASTA format but I can't find a way to convert this into a [format that haploview accepts](http://www.broadinstitute.org/science/programs/medical-and-population-genetics/haploview/input-file-formats-0).

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get from a FASTA format file (e.g. >Az01|Female|Azores AGGATCT...) to a phased haplotype format (Az01    Azores    0    4    2    2)?

Comment: You should let us know how your fasta files are like. What is your reference etc? These are the reads or assembled genomes?

Comment: @Luigi Collapser would just collapse redundant reads to a single sequence.

Comment: Shoot, I linked to the wrong tool!

Comment: What are your sequences? PED format is for SNP data, but I suspect you have a single gene.

Comment: I'm rather new to bioinformatics, so please excuse me if I'm a bit slow. They are reads of the ITS region of a shark species, and they're 910 bps long. I did produce a haplotype diagram in TCS, but I was told haploview was better. I'm looking at haplotypes from different geographic regions.

Comment: @WillPerry You can try this: Align reads → Get BAM → Get VCF (with GATK or something similar) → Convert to PED (VCFtools). There should be a better way; I am not aware of it.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thanks, I've converted the aligned reads to a BAM file but when trying to produce the VCF file I was asked for a reference file. Do you know what this reference file is meant to be comprised of? I'm using PGDSpider with samtools and bcftools extensions.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Also, when I opened the BAM file in notepad it was unreadable; "‹     ÿ BC ÚUÖÍnÓ@ÅqW,ÀH¼Jå{çÎ... etc". Is this normal?

Comment: Yes you would need a reference. Your reads also have to be mapped to the genome first, to generate the BAM, so that you know the positions where the reads align. Reference is fasta file for the genome. BAM is binary; it won't be readable. You can use samtools to read it. For more info on VCF see [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3137218/)

Comment: @WillPerry When I read your previous comment carefully I realized that you actually need not use haploview. You can try this: Collapse redundant reads (while keeping a count) → do multiple sequence alignment. I am suggesting this because you are interested in just one region. You don't need haploview and all.